# Lua unusual variable name (question mark variable)

Tags: lua

I have stumbled upon this line of code and I am not sure what the `[ ? ]` part represents (my guess is it's a sort of a wildcard but I searched it for a while and couldn't find anything):

```
['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end
```

I understand that RHS is a functional ternary operator. I am curious about the LHS and what it actually is.

Edit: reference (2nd example):

http://lua-users.org/wiki/SwitchStatement

Comment: Difficult to say without context, but it seems that this table describes answers to questions in some dialogue: someone prints `?` and receives `eh`, if the global/upvalue `is_canadian` evaluates to `true` or nothing. It's hardly some syntactic sugar: `t.?` will result in a syntax error. Table key `?` has no special meaning.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin what makes you think it's a table? There is no prefix such as `x[ ? ]`, it's literally just the access operator `[]` on the LHS, makes no sense in most programming languages, it's similar to having `+ = function () print("hi)" end`.

Comment: `['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end` should be a part of table declaration, e.g. `local t = {['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end}` or setting a table field: `t ['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end`. Outside of a table it will cause a syntax error. Of course, this can also be userdata with `__newindex` metamethod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is quite simple.

```
  local t = {
    a = "aah",
    b = "bee",
    c = "see",
```

It maps each letter to a sound pronunciation. Here, `a` need to be pronounced `aah` and `b` need to be pronounced `bee` and so on. Some letters have a different pronunciation if in `american english` or `canadian english`. So not every letter can be mapped to a single sound.

```
z = function() return is_canadian and "zed" or "zee" end,
['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end
```

In the mapping, the letter `z` and the letter `?` have a different prononciation in `american english` or `canadian english`. When the program will try to get the prononciation of `'?'`, it will calls a function to check whether the user want to use `canadian english` or another english and the function will returns either `zed` or `zee`.

Finally, the 2 following notations have the same meaning:

```
  local t1 = {
    a     = "aah",
    b     = "bee",
    ["?"] = "bee"
  }

  local t2 = {
    ["a"] = "aah",
    ["b"] = "bee",
    ["?"] = "bee"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes perfect sense!

One question thought, why is the last example the same? I always thought of Lua tables as maps from other programming language, hence having key + value for each element.

In my mind, `["a"] = "aah"` maps a string to a key of a string type. `a     = "aah"` here I am unsure what a is.

Comment: @Shibalicious this explained in my answer. `{a="aah"}` is short for `{["a"]="aah")}`. Please read it carefully. while Robert explains what the code does I explain why it needs to be written that way. as `a` is a letter and hence can be a Lua name you can use it in that shorter syntax.

Comment: Actually, `{ ["a"] = "aah" }` map the key `"a"` to the value `"aah"`. This notation is verbose and Lua provide a way to write it shorter, so there is the notation `{ a = "aah" }` which does exactly the same thing. But this special notation does not work with all the characters, for example `?`, `*`, `!`. So `{ ["a"] = "aah" }` is equivalent to `{ a = "aah" }`, but `{ ["?"] = "test" }` cannot be expressed with the special notation. `{ ? = "aah" }` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Robert sorry for the late reply, thank you, makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely at the code linked in the question, you'll see that this line is part of a table constructor (the part inside `{}`). It is not a full statement on its own. As mentioned in the comments, it would be a syntax error outside of a table constructor. `['?']` is simply a string key.

Comment: I have given best answer to another person only because their answer was more detailed and had some examples, your answer is excellent too though!

Answer (score 2):

The other posts alreay explained what that code does, so let me explain why it needs to be written that way.

`['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end` is embedded in `{}`

It is part of a [table constructor](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9) and assigns a function value to the string key `'?'`

`local tbl = {a = 1}` is syntactic sugar for `local tbl = {['a'] = 1}` or

```
local tbl = {}
tbl['a'] = 1
```

String keys that allow that convenient syntax must follow [Lua's lexical conventions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1) and hence may only contain letters, digits and underscore. They must not start with a digit.

So `local a = {? = 1}` is not possible. It will cause a syntax error `unexpected symbol near '?'` Therefor you have to explicitly provide a string value in square brackets as in `local a = {['?'] = 1}`

they gave each table element its own line

```
local a = {
    1,
    2,
    3
}
```

This greatly improves readability for long table elements or very long tables and allows you maintain a maximum line length.

You'll agree that

```
local tbl = {
    z     = function() return is_canadian and "zed" or "zee" end,
    ['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end
}
```

looks a lot cleaner than

`local tbl = {z = function() return is_canadian and "zed" or "zee" end,['?'] = function() return is_canadian and "eh" or "" end}`

Comment: I have given answer to another person as they were first to provide me with a detailed answer however your answer is top 2!